# Should I start with Trac 0.12?

Tags: trac

I'm going to start using Trac for the first time. From what I've gathered, the latest 0.12 is capable of supporting multiple project easily (which is something I will need since I got about 5 projects). However, it seems 0.12 is still in the development (0.12-dev). So, my question is, is it good enough for a newbie in Trac like me to use it? Does anyone has any experience using it ? It will be installed on a Linux server.

BTW, I'll only be using the basic functions such as svn browser, wiki, tickets and others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0.12 is only going to support a subset of multiple projects ([milestone](http://trac.edgewall.org/milestone/0.12)) - you can now connect multiple source repositories with a single Trac environment. you will still need to create your own logic for handling multiple projects inside that single environment, with ticket components or whathaveyou.

i'm running all envs on 0.12 trunk (currently) r9280, i follow trac development timeline and hand pick my next revision to upgrade to, when something important gets a fix. some of my environments have multiple svn and git repositories connected. svn is rock solid, GitPlugin occasionally causes some quirks (rev caching issues mainly), but for me it's all minor compared to the convenience i get.

i would definitely recommend moving straight to 0.12-dev, [i've already written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223285/what-headaches-should-i-expect-from-using-trac/2237830#2237830) a bit about some other benefits over 0.11.